# Is SPServices working different on https?

Tags: spservices, https

It seems like I can't access any Lists on https sites, I get the status -> error everytime I try. Tried GetList and GetListItems operations in my Javascript function, which works fine on any site I tested it - as I just have to change my "SITE_URL" parameter. The webURL and listName are given.

So I came to ask: Is SPServices working different on https?

EDIT: Someone coming across this question looking for similar issues may find this topic about CORS, different farms and HTTP / HTTPS useful: [Link](http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/358340)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, no. I've used it in both http and https environments without issues.

Comment: Accepting your answer, as it seems to be the correct answer to the actual question in my post, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that accessing data cross-protocols will breach [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You can get around this by using a [relative URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location#Relative_URL_example), or just start a full path URL with `//` instead of specifying protocol.

Comment: The CORS subject led me to another answer, thanks for the point.